# R auto.arima() vs arima() giving different result with the same model

Tags: r, time-series

I have a question about this time series analysis, with mean monthly air temperature (Deg. F) Nottingham Castle 1920-1939:

https://datamarket.com/data/set/22li/mean-monthly-air-temperature-deg-f-nottingham-castle-1920-1939#!ds=22li&display=line

When I ran

```
auto.arima(x.t,trace=True)
```

it gave me "ARIMA(5,0,1) with non-zero mean" and "AIC=1198.42" as the lowest AIC. However, when I manually input the arima model, I came across a model with even lower aic.

```
arima(x = x.t, order = c(3, 1, 3))
```

aic = 1136.95.
When I run the function `auto.arima(x.t,trace = TRUE,d=1),` It gave me ARIMA(2,1,2) with AIC of 1221.413. While  `ARIMA(3,1,3)` with drift gives 1209.947 and `ARIMA(3,1,3)` gives 1207.859.

I am really confused. I thought `auto.arima` should automatically suggest you the number of differencing. Why is `auto.arima` AIC different than the arima AIC while they have the same model?

Comment: You can't compare AIC values when there are different numbers of differences used.

Answer (score 0):

You're fitting two *different* ARIMA models. Obviously an ARIMA(5,0,1) model is not the same as an ARIMA(3,1,3) model. In the former, you model `p=5` time lags with no differencing, whereas in the latter you consider `p=3` time lags with `d=1` degree of differencing. Additionally, your model's MA components are also different: `q=1` vs. `q=3`.

Different models will obviously give you different quality metrics (i.e. different AICs).

Comment: I think you misterpret my question. I have three model 
model1=auto.arima(dataset$Temperature,trace = TRUE)
model2=arima(dataset$Temperature,order = c(3,1,3))
model3=auto.arima(dataset$Temperature,trace = TRUE,d=1)

Comment: model 1 with auto arima, never consider any model with differencing. I thought it should have been automatically do that.

Comment: I force model 3 to do 1 differencing and it gave me arima(2,1,2) with AIC= 1221.413
In when I use trace=TRUE, it will also calculate other model that the function auto.arima dismissed. In model 3, the auto.arima calculate ARIMA(3,1,3), aic=1207.859 . A much smaller aic. The model3 also display this “
Now re-fitting the best model(s) without approximations...

 ARIMA(3,1,3)                    : Inf
 ARIMA(3,1,3) with drift         : Inf
 ARIMA(2,1,2)                    : 1221.413
“

Comment: When I use model 2 the under the same model, (3,1,3), I have a totally different  aic. arima(x = x.t, order = c(3, 1, 3)) aic = 1136.95.

Comment: @ThaiPhi Please don't comment-spam! I agree with you in that it's not clear to me what you're after. You have **different** models. So obviously the AICs will be **different**. When you do `arima(x = x.t, order = c(3, 1, 3))` you run an ARIMA(3,1,3) model **with 1 degree of differencing**. This will give you a different AIC to that of an ARIMA(5, 0, 1) model. Your statement *"never consider any model with differencing"* makes no sense to me, as you explicitly run an ARIMA(3,1,3) model. So again, different models obviously lead to different performances (i.e. AICs)!

Comment: Please read my comment carefully, it is important not spam.The coment box are limited so I have to break it down. when you use auto.arima() with trace=TRUE. it will run all of the model and calculate their aic. In model3 when I force it to calculate d=1, chose (2,1,2) with aic of 1221.413.It also ran and analyze many model includes the (3,1,3) with the aic of 1207.859 .  However, if I ran (3,1,3) separately using arima(), I have a diferent aic for (3,1,3) which is 1136.95

Comment: @ThaiPhi Rest assured that I'm reading your comments *very* carefully. I suggest you do the same. Your question is not clear, not from the main body&title, nor from your comments. Either way we're going around in circles, perhaps somebody else will be able to assist. Cheers.